# Throttle service with multiple, independant callers

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to ensure that a given API call is throttled so that for a given time interval, only a single request is fired, and that the other, throttled requests wait and receive the results of the request that was actively fired

**Example**

```
const generateReport = (args) => client.get(...)

const generateReportA = (argsForA) =>
    generateReport(argsForA).then(saveReportSomewhere)

const generateReportB = (argsForB) =>
    generateReport(argsForB).then(saveReportSomewhere)

const generateReportC = (argsForC) =>
    generateReport(argsForC).then(saveReportSomewhere)
```

If we then run the statements below

```
generateReportA(...).then(console.log) // should log result of C
generateReportB(...).then(console.log) // should log result of C
generateReportC(...).then(console.log) // should log result
```

right after each other, I only want to fire the request associated with `generateReportC` and I'd like both `generateReportA` and `generateReportB` to receive and handle the result of `generateReportC`.

In the end `generateReport` should have been called once and `saveReportSomewhere` should have been called 3 times, each with the result from `generateReportC`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This will fire `C` request get result and save it, then trigger `A` and `B` at the same time with result from `C` and save results immediately after every emit.

```
generateReportC.pipe(
    tap(cResult => saveReportSomewhere(cResult)),
    mergeMap(cResult => merge(generateReportA(cResult), generateReportB(cResult))),
    tap(result => saveReportSomewhere(result))
).subscribe();
```